# How to put buttons on anywhere in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put buttons in not in the order

So what is the suitable layout (without absolute layout) and how can I put this image in that 
layout?

In absolute layout we can put buttons anywhere in the layout like that I want do this without using absolute layout.

Comment: Make your question a little more clear

Comment: I'm guessing English is not your first language, so I'm trying to have extra patience, but I really don't think your question makes any sense.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: I believe Table Layout will do the trick(not very neat though). You can put this image as an Image or as background of a LinearLayout

Comment: the think I want to know is In absolute layout we can put buttons anywhere in the layout like that I want do this without using absolute layout.

Comment: Why can't you use `AbsoluteLayout`?

Comment: it is deprecated so less flexible and harder to maintain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FrameLayout` and position your buttons using `android:layout_margin` tags. This way you can position your views in any place you want. Be careful with not using `px` as measurement unit to make your layout look the same on different devices. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

I'm not sure you'll be able to make this layout look nice on all screen sizes though. You'll need some code to ensure that (like detecting overlaps, and changing coordinates/padding/margins whenever needed).

Its probably better to calculate absolute coordinates in code using current screen dimensions, and just avoid using xml layout in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

AbsoluteLayout

but I do not know how to respond to the screen resolution. I have all the good works that under the Desire HD that under Desire.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and it is discouraged to use it.